# How to merge dataframes and fill values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am trying to merge the 2 DataFrames below to get an output where each code is listed on each date and the quantity is filled as 0 if the code was not in the original dataframe on that date. I have put an example of my input and desired output below but my live data will have over a years worth of dates and over 20,000 codes.

Input data:

df1

```
    date
0   2021-05-03
1   2021-05-04
2   2021-05-05
3   2021-05-06
4   2021-05-07
5   2021-05-08
6   2021-05-09
7   2021-05-10
```

df2

```
    date      code  qty
0   2021-05-03  A   2
1   2021-05-06  A   5
2   2021-05-07  A   4
3   2021-05-08  A   5
4   2021-05-10  A   6
5   2021-05-04  B   1
6   2021-05-08  B   4
```

Desired Output:

```
date      code  qty
03/05/2021  A   2
03/05/2021  B   0
04/05/2021  A   0
04/05/2021  B   1
05/05/2021  A   0
05/05/2021  B   0
06/05/2021  A   5
06/05/2021  B   0
07/05/2021  A   4
07/05/2021  B   0
08/05/2021  A   5
08/05/2021  B   4
09/05/2021  A   0
09/05/2021  B   0
10/05/2021  A   6
10/05/2021  B   0
```

I have tried the below merge but the output I get does not seem to be as desired:

```
df_new = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='date')


    date      code  qty
0   2021-05-03  A   2.0
1   2021-05-04  B   1.0
2   2021-05-05  NaN NaN
3   2021-05-06  A   5.0
4   2021-05-07  A   4.0
5   2021-05-08  A   5.0
6   2021-05-08  B   4.0
7   2021-05-09  NaN NaN
8   2021-05-10  A   6.0
```

Comment: I assume you want all combinations of dates and codes right?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get all combinations of dates and codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `cross-join` between `df1` and `unique vals` of `code`. Then use `df.fillna()`:

```
In [480]: x = pd.DataFrame(df2.code.unique())

In [483]: y = df1.assign(key=1).merge(x.assign(key=1), on='key').drop('key', 1).rename(columns={0: 'code'})

In [486]: res = y.merge(df2, how='left').fillna(0)

In [487]: res
Out[487]: 
          date code  qty
0   2021-05-03    A  2.0
1   2021-05-03    B  0.0
2   2021-05-04    A  0.0
3   2021-05-04    B  1.0
4   2021-05-05    A  0.0
5   2021-05-05    B  0.0
6   2021-05-06    A  5.0
7   2021-05-06    B  0.0
8   2021-05-07    A  4.0
9   2021-05-07    B  0.0
10  2021-05-08    A  5.0
11  2021-05-08    B  4.0
12  2021-05-09    A  0.0
13  2021-05-09    B  0.0
14  2021-05-10    A  6.0
15  2021-05-10    B  0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

This is better suited for a `reindex`. You create all combinations, set the index, reindex to all of those combinations, fillna and then reset the index.

```
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.date, df2['code'].unique()],
                                 names=['date', 'code'])

df2 = (df2.set_index(['date', 'code'])
          .reindex(idx)
          .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
          .reset_index())
```

---

```
          date code  qty
0   2021-05-03    A    2
1   2021-05-03    B    0
2   2021-05-04    A    0
3   2021-05-04    B    1
4   2021-05-05    A    0
5   2021-05-05    B    0
6   2021-05-06    A    5
7   2021-05-06    B    0
8   2021-05-07    A    4
9   2021-05-07    B    0
10  2021-05-08    A    5
11  2021-05-08    B    4
12  2021-05-09    A    0
13  2021-05-09    B    0
14  2021-05-10    A    6
15  2021-05-10    B    0
```

Comment: I think it should be ```from_product([df1.date.unique() + df2.date.unique(), df2.code.unique()]```

Comment: @FloLie For the dates, since it's a `'left'` merge I assume the basis should only be df1. The codes could be done that way, but if there's only 2, and it's possible it's missing from df2, could be safer to just specify them.

Comment: Nice one, probably replace `['A','B']` with `df2.code.unique()`?

Comment: @ALollz, you are right, that it depends upon the assumption. For the dates its true, if df1 is a full calender, but for the codes I would mark ["A","B"] as a variable named all_codes or else take the unique values from df2

Answer (score 3):

One option with `pivot` and `stack`:

```
(df2.pivot_table(index='date', columns='code', fill_value=0)
    .reindex(df1.date, fill_value=0)
    .stack('code')
    .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
          date code  qty
0   2021-05-03    A    2
1   2021-05-03    B    0
2   2021-05-04    A    0
3   2021-05-04    B    1
4   2021-05-05    A    0
5   2021-05-05    B    0
6   2021-05-06    A    5
7   2021-05-06    B    0
8   2021-05-07    A    4
9   2021-05-07    B    0
10  2021-05-08    A    5
11  2021-05-08    B    4
12  2021-05-09    A    0
13  2021-05-09    B    0
14  2021-05-10    A    6
15  2021-05-10    B    0
```